# "Fathers shall not be put to death because of sons, nor shall sons be put to death because of fathers" - Contradiction?

Tags: sin, parashat-shelach, ki-teitzei

[Devarim 24:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9988/jewish/Chapter-24.htm)

> Fathers shall not be put to death because of sons, nor shall sons be put to death because of fathers; each man shall be put to death for his own transgression.

Here is a passuk most people are familiar with. However, while reading last week's parsha (Shelach), I noticed an intriguing passuk that seems to contradict the above statement in Devarim.

[Bamidbar 14:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9942)

> 'The Lord is slow to anger and abundantly kind, forgiving iniquity and transgression, Who cleanses [some] and does not cleanse [others], Who visits the iniquities of parents on children, even to the third and fourth generations.'

(The translation of the passukim are from Chabad.org)

There is something I do not understand here. G-d says he punishes the children for the sins of their parents to the third and fourth generations, but later says that if a father sins, the children should not be held accountable and vice-versa. Am I missing something here? I checked in Rashi but he does not comment on the seemingly apparent contradiction.

Comment: also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67782/7539

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/why-did-god-sanction-killing-everything-that-breathes-against-the-7-nations

Comment: (That thing where you read an answer, go to upvote, and find you can't. :-) ) Is this a duplicate of the question @Rish linked?  I have an answer there, so I'm not the best person to judge.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The answer would apply here, but I don't think the question is a dupe.

Comment: A din from shamayim rather than a din nefashot from a b"d

Comment: My comment that I'd intended to expand into an answer was deleted. Quite annoying, as the off-the-cuff response was worded better than the researched answer.

Comment: Check out Ezekiel 18

Comment: The first passage speaks about capital punishment; the second, about delaying the full acceptance of formerly pagan(ized) nations into the nation or land of Israel; see also Deuteronomy 23:3. After all, even for a single individual to convert from one mindset to another it sometimes takes years, if not decades; let alone for an entire nation: it would probably take several centuries or generations. Certain processes simply require a considerable amount of time to come to full fruition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gemara in [Meseches Brachos 7a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7a.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says the following addressing this seeming "contradiction":

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> **והא כתיב (שמות לד, ז) פקד עון אבות על בנים וכתיב (דברים כד, טז) ובנים לא יומתו על אבות ורמינן קראי אהדדי ומשנינן לא קשיא הא כשאוחזין מעשה אבותיהם בידיהם הא כשאין אוחזין מעשה אבותיהם בידיהם**
>
> *But it is written (Exoudus 34:7) "Who accounts the sin of the fathers upon the children" and it is written (Deut. 24:16) "..and the sons shall not die becuase of the (sins of their) fathers' " (How do can we reconcile these two seemingly contradictory verses?). We learn that it is not difficult, this (verse) is when they are holding onto (the wicked) deeds of their fathers in their hands (like their own) and this (verse) is when they are not holding (the wicked) deed of their fathers'*  <sup>1</sup>

Hope this is helpful!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Additionally for further insight see the Gemara in [Makkos 24a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.24a.36?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) about the prophets nullifying four decrees of Moshe and the Maharsha's commentary (in Chidushei Agados) (ibid.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The "9 Attributes" verse in Parshas Shelach (Bamidbar 14:18) is a parallel (not quite a mirror) of the "13 Attributes" in Parshas Ki Sisa (Shemos 34:6-7). The phrase "... visits the iniquities of parents on children, etc." is present in both verses, as well as in the Aseres Hadibros (in both Yisro and Va'eschanan). Rashi on the other verses is more verbose than he is here.

Targum Onkelos in Shelach and Yisro translates פקד עון אבות על בנים as מסער חובי אבהן על בנין מרדין (adding the adjective "rebelious" to "the children"). Targum on the Aseres Hadibros goes further and adds the explanatory phrase: כד משלמין בניא למחטי בתר אבהתהון (when the sons continue sinning after their fathers). Rashi quotes this Targum both ad loc. and on the 13 Attributes: כשאוחזים מעשה אבותיהם בידיהם.

Although Rashi in Shelach does not quote this distinction, I believe it can be understood the same way.

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA Quoting Rashi and Targum, including the Targum on the verse the OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

In his commentary to a similar verse in [Exodus 20:4-5](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#4), [Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) explains that the punishment that God inflicts on children for the sins of their fathers is not a direct punishment, but it is a natural consequence. He explains this by giving an example wherein the fathers commit a sin which earns them the punishment of being exiled among the nations. Their children will thus be born into exile – not because God is "punishing" them, but because that is simply the natural state of affairs. If your parents are in exile then you will *nolens volens* be born in exile. If the children manage to attain high levels of perfection it is possible that God will intervene and rescue them from exile, but if they merely refrain from doing bad things that won't be enough to stimulate a Divine intervention.

Thus, what the verse means when it says that children are punished for their fathers's sins is that the fathers' sins will indirectly cause the children's suffering, but not that God specifically exacts retribution on the children for sins that they haven't committed.

> והנה יסופק בזה המאמר ספק חזק  והוא  איך יתכן שיענוש ה' יתעלה בני החוטא  והנה אין להם אשם בחטא אביהם  ואנחנו מתירין זה הספק בזה האופן  והוא  שהעונש יביא ה' יתעלה לעוברים על דבריו  אם על צד ההשגחה על דרך התוכחת  אם על צד סור ההשגחה שיחולו עליהם הרעות הנכונות לבוא עליהם מצד המערכת  וכבר יהיו אלו הרעות באופן שיגיע בהם רע לזרעם לא היה מגיע להם לולא חטא אבותיהם  והמשל  כי כאשר מרו אבותינו חוייב להם מהעונש שיגלו בין האומות ויירשו גוים ארצם  והנה נמשך לזרעם אחריהם הגלות הזה בסיבת המצאם גולים בהולדם  עד שלא יתכן שימלטו מזה הרע אם לא בהיותם יוצאים ממנו על צד המערכת  או בשיהיו בתכלית השלמות שיתכן שיוציאם ה' יתעלה מהארצות אשר הדיחם שם על דרך המופת  ובזה האופן היה מה שאמר הנביא  אבֹתינו חטאו ואינם ואנחנו עונֹתיהם סבלנו וזה  שאם לא חטאו אבותינו היינו אנחנו נמצאים בארץ  ולא נצא ממנה אם לא בשנעשה מהפעולות המגונות מה שנתחייב עליהם כמו זה העונש  ואולם כשנמצאנו בגלות בחטא אבותינו  הנה לא יספיק לנו לשוב שם ההשמר מהפעולות המגונות  אבל יצטרך לנו שנקנה מהשלמות מה שנהיה בו דבקים בה' יתעלה באופן שיוציאנו מהגלות הזה על צד ההשגחה הנפלאה  ובזה האופן לא יהיה עוול אם יגיע עונש לבנים בעבור חטא אביהם  כי הוא במקרה

Ralbag further notes that the Sages resolve the difficulty in a different manner, by asserting that God punishes children for the sins of their fathers when the children continue in the sinful ways. Ralbag agrees that this is true and explains it as follows: the punishment of God intended as a rebuke varies according to the severity of the sin. If someone merely did their own sin than a lesser rebuke would suffice to snap them out of it. But when children are entrenched in the sinful ways of their fathers it is much harder to return them to the straight path, and therefore  a greater rebuke is necessary:

> ואולם רבותינו ז"ל התירו זה הספק באופן אחר  וזה  שהם אמרו שה' יתעלה הוא פוקד עוון אבות על בנים כאשר יהיו הבנים אוחזים מעשה אבותיהם בידיהם  והוא בלי ספק מאמר אמיתי  כמו שביארנו ברביעי מספר מלחמות ה' וזה  כי הרע המסודר מה' יתעלה על צד התוכחת יהיה לפי המרי  רוצה לומר שמי שהסתבך במרי סיבוך מועט   תספיק לו תוכחת מעוטה  ומי שהחזיק בו באופן ששב לו קנין חזק   יצטרך לתוכחת יותר עצומה  ובהיות הענין כן  הנה כאשר חטא האדם לבדו   תספיק לו תוכחת יותר מעוטה מהתוכחת אשר תצטרך לו אם היה מחזיק אביו בזאת התכונה והיה הוא אוחז מעשה אבותיו  כי אז נסתבך בזה המרי סיבוך יותר חזק  ובזה האופן אמרה התורה  ואף בעונת אבתם אתם ימקו והנה מה שאמרנוהו בזה הוא יותר נאות לפי הפשט

Ralbag also discusses this extensively in Milchamot Hashem 4:6.